# For Continuous Delivery and Deployment, does it go really directly to production?

Tags: continuous-integration, theory, continuous-deployment

Having read about these concepts, I wonder whether the authors by "production" mean really the customer's environment.

I mean, I would expected that Continuous Integration and Deployment analyzes the code, runs the unit tests, builds the product and delivers it to our System Integration Testing environment. Or in general, I would expect that CI/CD assembles the build for QA/QC, i.e. manual or automated tests driven by test engineers.

Answer (score 0):

In a context in which all SIT/QA/QC activities would be entirely automated and pulled into the final stages of the CI/CD system would you see a problem if deployment would happen directly into the customer environment?

Of course, it's also a matter of confidence in the processes and tools, culture and traditions (or ability to change them), product/application purpose and risk/impact of deployment failure, customer relations, etc. But IMHO there is no technical reason why this would be inconceivable or undesired, at least in some cases.